# Create APK at runtime using Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have an android App it is called ScrapperMin (you can find in play store).
Basically it does parsing on script that user create and able to run the script on the App itself, however the App has multiple script for multi purposes.

I want to let the user of ScrapperMin able to create a new APK from ScrapperMin which include only one script and the new APK's purpose is to run only that script. And let the user to change the new APK app name & icon and the APK file included with the script. So the new APK when run will display user input and run and thats it, no editor of script which confuses layman user

Basically what in my mind

- Create a generic APK that looks for a script in the resource strings and generate UI to let user input the user input required by the script
- Bundle that APK into ScrapperMin
- In ScrapperMin after user finish writing their script, user click a Generate APK button, ScrapperMin will copy the generic APK from its resources (like dropper) and include selected script and put the script inside the resources APK file, but is that possible? How to do it? Any example?
- How about changing the Icon and name of the new APK?

The reason I want to do this is to let user create their own APK after writing the script and distribute to their clients.